# Colour laser printer has faded and powdery magenta toner

Tags: laser-printer

Other cartridges and black print fine. I've tried two different brands of Magenta toner and it was working perfectly well until recently. The problem didn't coincide with a new toner cartridge as far as I can recall. The printer is a Dell 1350cnw. When I print the test page the Magenta is perhaps slightly faded but not too bad and smooth. When I print an image that should have some red or brown areas it comes out a muddy greenish colour and has a distinctively powdery texture. Thoughts on trouble-shooting welcomed.

Comment: What image are you printing? And what program do you use?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter too much - word, pdf, image - all have same symptoms. Here's a link to an image that comes out greenish instead of reddish: http://timvandevall.com/wp-content/uploads/treasure-chest-template-02.jpg

Comment: If the test page is ok, that leads me to think that it's got to do with the computer/system or the connection. Are you printing from the same computer? Maybe the driver isn't working. Or there might be a hardware problem with the connection. But it's weird that the ink has a powdery texture. Can you try printing something that is supposed to be pure magenta?

Comment: I think the two brands of inks may be incompatible. The brown areas in the image are composed of about 20% cyan, 60% magenta, 30% yellow and 30% black. Can you try printing the following image to test this theory?http://iremaltan.com/test.jpg

Comment: Different brands of toner can vary in color, grain size, and melting point.  Sounds like incompatible toner.

Comment: Hi, it seems the duff toner hadn't worked through the system completely despite some test prints, clean / refresh cycles etc. It is now printing correctly. I think @sodiumnitrate was correct and the magenta I had in the printer (despite being same brand as the other toner cartridges) was in some way defective making it faded and incompatible with the other colours. Feel free to post it as answer for the points. Thanks for your help and the test image.

Comment: @AndyBoura I'm glad to have helped. I'll post an answer and include the test page, so someone else with a color mixing problem might find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is an incompatibility between the toners. If magenta alone works well, but its mixture with other colors causes a problem, than this is very likely. I have a test page [here](http://iremaltan.com/test.jpg), which includes boxes filled with 5 colors:

1. magenta
2. 50% magenta, 50% cyan
3. 50% magenta, 50% yellow
4. 50% magenta, 50% black
5. 30% cyan, 60% magenta, 50% yellow, and 50% black

If magenta prints out ok but others are powdery and of the wrong color, then we can rule out a connectivity/driver problem, and conclude that there is a mixing problem.